# MySql 8.0.17 Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server

Tags: mysql, authentication, node.js

I'm trying to connect my Node JS application with my MySQL database, but I was getting the client does not support error. So I followed the steps given on the Stack Overflow for that, but I am still getting the same error.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 8 uses `caching_sha2_password` by default, but your version of Node.JS do not support this, it seems.

You may alter the user password type using

```
ALTER USER 'foo'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'bar';
```

[read about](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/native-pluggable-authentication.html)

Comment: I tried this query and but then also on connecting from nodejs it is showing the same error.